# C++ Address Book

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to make it so if userselection = 1, then the user is asked questions  to create their contact for an address book. It saves all of the contact info to a struct and then saves to a .txt file. I am very new to C++. This is what I have so far... I keep getting  **[Error] expected primary-expression before '.' token.** <---- HOW CAN I FIX THIS
Also, can anyone offer guidance for how to save the struct to a file?
Thanks.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;



struct person{
         string Name;
         string Address;
         string PhoneNumber;
         string Email;
             };

 int main(){
int userselection = 0;


cout << "What do you want to do? Press 1 to Add Contact -- Press 2 to Search       for Contact"<<endl;
 cin >> userselection;


if(userselection == '1');
  person newPerson;
  cout << "What is your Name?" << endl;
  cin >> person.Name;
  cout << "What is your Address?" << endl;
  cin >> person.Address;
  cout << "What is your Phone Number?" << endl;
  cin >> person.PhoneNumber;
  cout << "What is your Email?" << endl;
  cin >> person.Email;


  }
```

Comment: `cin >> newPerson.Name;`, a.s.o.

Comment: Also, `if(userselection == '1');` does nothing (mind the trailing semicolon)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the error you describe, you need to access members in the class instance, not the class definition ..

```
newPerson.Name
```

rather than

```
person.Name
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mistakes were simply associated with syntax. Please read your compiler's error messages in the future.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>    // added 
using namespace std;

struct person {
    string Name;
    string Address;
    string PhoneNumber;
    string Email;
};

int main() {
    int userselection = 0;

    cout << "What do you want to do? Press 1 to Add Contact -- Press 2 to Search for Contact"<<endl;
    cin >> userselection;

    if(userselection == 1) { // userselection is int so why compare it to char
        person newPerson;
        cout << "What is your Name?" << endl;
        cin >> newPerson.Name; // assign to object's member not a static member
        cout << "What is your Address?" << endl;
        cin >> newPerson.Address;
        cout << "What is your Phone Number?" << endl;
        cin >> newPerson.PhoneNumber;
        cout << "What is your Email?" << endl;
        cin >> newPerson.Email;
    }

}
```